# Create a login system in Java using Arraylist

Tags: java, authentication, arraylist, modular

I'm a junior developer and for my project, my goal is to start with a login.

I tried to check the ID and Password on the same function, individually, one inside another like the one I'll show next

I've got an Employee class:

```
public class Empleado{
    private String id;
    private String passwd;

    public Empleado(String id, String passwd) {
        this.id = id;
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

}
```

And this is how far I've gotten on Main:

```
String identificador;
boolean idCheck;
String contrasena;
boolean passCheck;

ArrayList<Empleado> misEmpleados = new ArrayList<>();
misEmpleados.add(new Empleado("EmpleadoA","passA"));
misEmpleados.add(new Empleado("EmpleadoB","passB"));
misEmpleados.add(new Empleado("EmpleadoC","passC"));

do{
  System.out.print("Enter ID: ");
  identificador = input.next();

  idCheck = comprobarId(false, identificador, misEmpleados);
}while(!idCheck);

public boolean comprobarId(boolean check, String id, ArrayList<Empleado> recepcionistas){
        String contrasena;

        for (int i = 0; i < recepcionistas.size(); i++) {

            if(recepcionistas.get(i).getId().equals(id)){

                System.out.print("Introducir contraseña: ");
                contrasena = input.next();

                check = comprobarPass(id, contrasena, recepcionistas);
            }
        }
        return check;
    }


public boolean comprobarPass(String id, String pass, ArrayList<Empleado> recepcionistas){

        for (int i = 0; i < recepcionistas.size(); i++) {

            if(recepcionistas.get(i).getId().equals(pass)){
                check = true;
            }
        }
        return check;
    }
```

Hope someone could help me a bit... Been struggling with this for 7 hours now.

Excuse my english and any other mistake, this is my first post/question

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already get the `Empleado` corresponding to the input id, pass only this `Empleado` to the `comprobarPass` method and not the whole list `recepcionistas`.

In your code, you are trying to do the job twice by looping in both method.

If you do the loop only once, to find the empleado, you don't need to do it again and you can use the empleado reference.

Another issue with you code is the 2 variables `check`: You set the value of a variable `check` in the method `comprobarPass` but this variable is not declared. Plus, in the `comprobarId` the primitive boolean`check`variable is passed as a parameter, modified then returned. This usage of primitive type variable is a bad practice. Prefer to remove this parameter and return a local variable.

Rule of thumb: The simpler, the better!

```
public boolean comprobarId(String id, ArrayList<Empleado> recepcionistas){
    String contrasena;
    boolean check = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < recepcionistas.size(); i++) {

        if(recepcionistas.get(i).getId().equals(id)){

            System.out.print("Introducir contraseña: ");
            contrasena = input.next();

            check = comprobarPass(contrasena, recepcionistas.get(i)); // pass the empleado, not the list
        }
    }
    return check;
}


public boolean comprobarPass(String pass, Empleado recepcionista){
    return recepcionista.getPasswd().equals(pass));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jhamon, i knew i was on the right track but couldn't make it work. What i was trying was to create an integer variable to store the position and then pass it as parameter.. Also i really appreciate your observation to make a good practice

Answer (score -1):

In your `comprobarPass` function, you're comparing the employee Id to the password, rather than the password. I think you mean to change this

```
if(recepcionistas.get(i).getId().equals(pass)){
    check = true;
}
```

to this

```
Empleado e = recepcionistas.get(i);
if(e.getId().equals(id) && e.getPasswd().equals(pass)){
    check = true;
}
```

This will instead check if both the id and password are a match, in one function rather than having a separate check for both id and password comparison

Comment: this will check that the password matches the one of any user so the behaviour is wrong